# Why does my rand() produce a negative number?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this bit of code when trying to create a random number between n and n^2, and somehow it sometimes produces a negative number. I've checked `rand()` and `time(NULL)` and both of them produce a positive number, so how can it be possible for it to produce a negative number as the result?

I'm suppose to generate many numbers to store into an array, but somehow only the first few numbers are negative.

```
int randomNum = (((rand()*time(NULL))%(n*n-n))+n);
```

Comment: My guess would be, `rand() * time(NULL)` results in integer overflow when `rand()` happens to generate a sufficiently large number, whereupon the code exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Why is `time(NULL)` used here? Remember if you generate in a loop time(NULL) will likely be the same number fore each iteration because the resolution is in seconds.

Comment: You could cast both sides of the multiplication to `unsigned int` first. Unsigned integer multiplication doesn't cause Undefined Behavior on overflow, but well-defined wrap-around. Still numerically weird, but not a bug.

Answer (score 4):

Integer overflow. `time(NULL)` currently returns a value around 1.49 billion. Multiplying that by `rand()` will overflow on almost any value of `rand()`, and will result in a negative value about half of the time.

Don't multiply by `time(NULL)`. It serves no purpose here. Just use `rand()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is *seed* the random number generator *once* with the time

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

After this, call the function without involving the time

```
int randomNum = ((rand()%(n*n-n))+n);
```

Seeding the random number generator repeatedly is a bad idea especially with time. In c++11 there are better ways to do this with `std::random`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41996058/7538586) given by [Raziman T V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2599610/raziman-t-v). If you write in C++11, then I strongly recommend using new ‘generators’ and ‘distributions’.  ‘Generators’ replace ‘rand()’ and allow generating pseudo-random numbers that are evenly distributed (like ‘rand()’). 'Distributions' transform the sequence of generated numbers according to the given distribution (uniform, normal, Weibull, etc). More information can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/). 
Here is example how you can generate pseudo-random numbers in the range [10; 20]:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

....
const size_t Min = 10, Max = 20;
size_t seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

// Similarly to srand(time(NULL))
std::mt19937_64 generator(seed); 
//uniform distribution from 10 to 20
std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> distribution(Min, Max); 

//Similarly to rand ()
size_t random = distribution(generator);
```

The main advantage is you can use an arbitrary number of generators (initialized with different seeds) and distributions to generate different pseudo-random sequences. It would be hard to generate two different sequences simultaneously with ‘rand()’.